# Why are factors of $2\pi$ inside transformed functions ignored in Fourier transform's different forms?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

The Fourier transform is defined as $$ \hat{f}(\xi) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \xi} dx $$

And the inverse Fourier transform as:

$$ f(x) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \hat{f}(\xi) e^{+2\pi i x \xi} d\xi $$

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Units_and_duality)

they make the following substitution $\omega = 2\pi\xi$ to get the following form of the equations from the first 2 equations I have written above:

Fourier transform:
$$ \hat{x}_1(\omega) = \hat{x}(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x(t) e^{-i t \omega} dx $$
Inverse Fourier transform
$$ x(t) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \hat{x}_1(\omega) e^{+ i t \omega} d\omega = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \hat{x}(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}) e^{+ i t \omega} d\omega  $$

Surely one must take note of the $\hat{x}(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})$ in the inverse transform, but everywhere I look I just see $\hat{x}(\omega)$ used in the inverse transform.

Likewise for the alternate form of the Fourier and inverse Fourier transforms with the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ factor in front, they are always written in terms of $x(t)$ and $\hat{x}(\omega)$ not $x(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2\pi}})$ and $\hat{x}(\frac{\omega}{\sqrt{2\pi}})$.

Why is this? Why can these factors be seemingly ignored?

Comment: Depends whether the frequency variable is temporal frequency $\xi$ or angular frequency $\omega$. Mathematicians usually prefer to work exclusively with the latter, though the question of whether to use the unitary normalization or the "PDE normalization" (the one convenient for mapping derivatives to multiplication operators without any factors of $2\pi$) still causes variation between authors.

Comment: Can you just set $\hat{x}(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})$ = $\hat{x}(\omega)$ for some reason then?

Comment: If your working with time at the variable $t$ (so you have $x(t)$) don't you have to use temporal frequency in the fourier transform (so you have $\hat{x}(\xi) = \hat{x}(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})$)?

Comment: Why would you be forced to use temporal frequency? It just depends how you define everything. No, you can't just replace $\xi$ by $\omega$ but you can define the FT to be in terms of $\omega$ in the first place.

Comment: On wikipedia it says 'in physical applications, ξ must have inverse units to the units of t. For example, if t is measured in seconds, ξ should be in cycles per second for the formulas here to be valid. If the scale of t is changed and t is measured in units of 2π seconds, then either ξ must be in the so-called "angular frequency", or one must insert some constant scale factor into some of the formulas.'

Comment: I just understood why this is the case from talking to a colleague. It is because the limits are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ so the variable in the function can be substituted without changing the result.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is because the bounds of the integral are $-\infty$ and $\infty$.

So we have the following Inverse Fourier transform
$$ x(t) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \hat{x}_1(\omega) e^{+ i t \omega} d\omega = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \hat{x}(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}) e^{+ i t \omega} d\omega  $$

but since $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(\frac{y}{2\pi})dy = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(y)dy$ for any variable $y$ we can simply exchange the $\hat{x}(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})$ inside the integral for $\hat{x}(\omega)$ like so:

$$ x(t) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \hat{x}(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}) e^{+ i t \omega} d\omega = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \hat{x}(\omega) e^{+ i t \omega} d\omega  $$

Comment: That is not right. The temporal FT and the angular FT are not literally the same function. You get the temporal FT if you have the $2\pi$ in the exponent of the forward transform. You get the angular FT if you don't. The inverse FT then changes its formula to compensate depending on the convention of the forward FT.

Comment: So then how does the reverse Fourier transform in terms of angular frequency look when you use the temporal Fourier transform? In the literature I always see the final form I have given here.

Comment: The inverse in the "PDE normalization" when the transform is defined in terms of angular frequency looks like the final form you wrote in your answer. I don't really know why you would mix the two frequencies by using one as the argument of the transform and integrating with respect to the other in the inverse transform. Generally people stick to one or the other.